# WebView custom error page is not shown instantly

Tags: android, webview

I use this code to redirect a user to a custom error page when the webView got errors however the browser error on the webpage is visible for a few milliseconds before redirecting to the custom error page.

The funny thing is that I have a *try again button* in **error.html** which tries to connect to the target webpage again. When I do fast clicks on try again, I can even see the browser error page clearly e.g. 404 page with the browser message **web page is not available**! This is not good because I want to completely hide the error especially the address of the webpage caused error which is visible in the browser error page.

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    webview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmls/error.html");
        }
    });
};
```

How should I hide the WebView instantly as soon as it receives an error? Is there another method to improve onReceivedError behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try This, this is the working code.

```
@Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Clearing the WebView
                try {
                    view.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    view.clearView();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (view.canGoBack()) {
                    view.goBack();
                }
                String ErrorPagePath = "file:///android_asset/htmls/error.html";
                view.loadUrl(ErrorPagePath);

                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked well however I used with two changes. I used `view.loadUrl("about:blank")` instead of `view.clearView()` as it is deprecated. also I removed `view.canGoBack()` because a common error is that the connection is not available and also redirects the user to an unwanted page.

Comment: `view.stopLoading()` did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `WebView view`,  but you are referencing `webview.post()` and `webview.loadUrl()`.

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView webview, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    webview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmls/error.html");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I just corrected this case when @perm posted an answer but no luck yet.